# How can I get rid of "add to cart" and "more" buttons in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

when I move my mouse cursor on top of each product there are 2  buttons that pop-up, these are: “add to cart” and ”more”. In which way can I get rid of them? I just want the possibility for my clients to click on the image of the product and let them go directly to the information page of each product (the one that displays various descriptions, quantity,...)

This "Display "add to cart" button when product has attributes = no" doesn't solve my problem.

I'am using prestashop 1.6.1.10

I've looked for information in other answers around the web but none of it seems to fit my problem.

thanks
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no option in back office to disable taht. But if you use the default theme, edit the file `/theme/default-bootstrap/product-list.tpl` and delete (or comment) from the `<div class="button-container">` until the next `</div>`

Comment: yes that is right and if you don't see any results you have to clear your cache, refresh the page and make sure that in "Advanced parameters" -> "Performance" -> "Template compilation" is set to "Recompile templates if the files have been updated" or "Force compilation", otherwise those files won't be updated.